# Azure DevOps User cant add tasks to sprint

Tags: azure-devops

I have a user who can get into a sprint, but cant add tasks to existing work items, and the green "+" symbol doesnt appear anywhere to add a new task.

In the sprint security the user has all 4 permissions :

```
Create child nodes ( inherited )
Delete this node
Edit this node
View Permissions
```

The user is also a member of a group which doesnt have "Delete this node" permissions in the sprint.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you check if this users' access level is set to 'Basic'? You can check that from org setting page under users tab.

Comment: The user is listed as Basic. But 2 other users who can add Tasks are also listed as Basic as well.